# Why does this python code give random numbers?

Tags: python

I need to fix this program it always gives me random numbers

```
def  count_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):


 print(int(hours * 3600) + int(minutes * 60) + int(seconds))

x = input("hours: ")
y = input("minutes: ")
z = input("seconds: ")
count_seconds(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Well you input different numbers everytime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` to integers before you perform calculations with them.

```
def  count_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
    print(hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds)

x = int(input("hours: "))
y = int(input("minutes: "))
z = int(input("seconds: "))
count_seconds(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct the int conversion like this

```
`def  count_seconds(he, me, se):

 print((int(he) * 3600) + (int(me) * 60) + (int(se)))

x = input("hours: ")
y = input("minutes: ")
z = input("seconds: ")
count_seconds(x, y, z)'
```